# Firebase Dynamic Deeplink: {SCHEME}://google/link/?dismiss=1&is_weak_match=1

Tags: swift, iphone, firebase, deep-linking

I have problems with Dynamic Deeplinks generated with Firebase SDK.
So to create dynamic deeplink:

```
guard let contentLink = URL(string: path) else { return }
let dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix = "https://link.mydomain.com/"
let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: contentLink, domainURIPrefix: dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix)
linkBuilder?.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "com.mydomain.app")
linkBuilder?.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "123123123"
linkBuilder?.iOSParameters?.customScheme = "mydomain"
linkBuilder?.androidParameters = DynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: "com.mydomain.android")

guard let dynamicLink = linkBuilder?.url?.absoluteString else { return }
```

here dynamicLink is the url which I share and open afterwards.

User clicks on link, it is opened in browser
[image]
User clicks OPEN and get's to desired link "contentLink", where user clicks on AppStore link and is redirected to proper app page, installs app, click OPEN there and then my app is launched, but:

launchOptions are nil and

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {}
```

is called and url = "{SCHEME}://google/link/?dismiss=1&is_weak_match=1"

QUESTION: What am I doing wrong and how could I get original dynamic deeplink or contentUrl?